# Why is variation defined $\partial y / \partial \alpha d\alpha$?

Tags: variational-calculus

Why is variation $\delta y$ not defined $\frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha}$ but $\frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha}d\alpha$ ?

($y(x) \to y(x, \alpha) = y(x, 0) + \alpha \eta(x)$)

cf. Goldstein p.38 eq 2.12:

$\left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha} \right)_0 d\alpha \equiv \delta y$

Answer (score 2):

For a generic 1D function, you have the following 1st order expansion:
$$y(\alpha + d\alpha) \approx y(\alpha) + \frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha} d\alpha$$
so your variation $\delta y = y(\alpha + d\alpha) - y(\alpha)  = \frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha} d\alpha$

Comment: The variation what I mean is derived this equation $y(x, \alpha) = y(x, 0) + \alpha \eta(x)$